# getting href after a search

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver

After a successful search, I need to get the hrefs that appear on the page after the search.

```
enter = present (driver, By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#search-submit")
driver.execute_script ("arguments[0].click()", enter)
elems = driver.find_elements_by_xpath ("//a[@href]")
# this for loop does not work 
for elem in elems:
     print(elem.get_attribute ("href"))
```

I am getting

> StaleElementReferenceException: Message: The element reference of  is stale

`driver.refresh()` does not fix the problem. `driver.back()` will         revove the search results. What else could be done?

> UPDATE

Florent B's. solution is the way to go. Today I have tested extensively,
works like a charm and faster

```
enter = self.present (driver, By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#search-submit")
driver.execute_script ("arguments[0].click()", enter)
**WebDriverWait (driver, 20).until (EC.staleness_of (enter))**
```

Comment: just for debugging purposes, if you add a sleep between the click and the findelements call of lets say 30 seconds, does this resolve the issue?

Comment: @MoeGhafari, thanks! sleep for 30 sec worked. If you put your suggestion as the answer i will gladly accept it.

Comment: The exception indicates that the page is reloaded while you are iterating the href. To overcome this issue, first wait for an element to become stale before iterating the links: `wait.until(EC.staleness_of(bt_submit))`

Comment: @FlorentB., What is bt_submit in my case?

Comment: @LetzerWille, `bt_submit` is a `WebElement` returned by `driver.find_element`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please put a sleep for 30 seconds prior to calling:

```
elems = driver.find_elements_by_xpath ("//a[@href]")
```

Glad this helped.

Edit:

You can execute this script via execute_script

```
"return window.jQuery && jQuery.active == 0"
```

which will return true IF all ajax requests are done if you prefer to avoid the sleep

Comment: Waiting a fixed amount of time for a stochastic event is unreliable and not recommended. If the page takes 1 second to load, you'll be wasting 29s and if it takes 31s, you'll still get the exception. The correct way to handle this is to use a waiter for either a stale or new element.

Comment: @FlorentB.I agree, the proposed solution was for debugging purposes only, nonetheless using a wait is also unreliable as you cant pre-run know how many hrefs will be on the page, the best approach would be to wait for the page to finish loading, and ensure all ajax requests are done.

Comment: using a waiter is reliable if you are waiting for the right state. The stale exception is usually raised when an element is used with a new document. This exception is not raised if the page is still loading.